# Showing a polygon in Mathematica

Tags: geometry

Could anyone be able to construct two shapes, a $n$-gon $P$ and a regular $n$-gon $Q$, say $n=5$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a regular polygon of $n$ points thusly:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], White, Polygon[CirclePoints[5]]}]
```

Or use `RegularPolygon[]`

[image]

For irregular polygons, you need to construct the points yourself:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], White, 
Polygon[{{3, 0}, {0, -Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks! Could you remove the black color in their interiors?

Comment: @DavidLabrecque Replace `Polygon` by `Line`

Comment: ...and `RegularPolygon[]` is built-in, too.

Comment: @Coolwater Possible, but then the first and last points don't connect.

Comment: @J.M. I'll add that, but considering he asked for both, I figured `Polygon[]` is more generic.

Comment: It's better to use `FaceForm[]` to remove the interior. See e.g. `Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, White]], FaceForm[], RegularPolygon[5]}, Background -> Blue]`.

Comment: @J.M. What's the difference here between `Faceform[]` and just setting `White`? Isn't it the same?

Comment: @Feyre, if the background is white, sure. That's why I gave an example in my previous comment. Try the snippet I gave with and without `FaceForm[]`.

Comment: @J.M. Sure, replacing `Faceform[]` with `Blue` works too. I figured `Faceform[]` was really only indicated form `Graphics3D[]`. If stylecode indicates `Faceform[]` I'll use it, just genuinely curious.

Comment: For an arbitrary set of `n` points: `Graphics[Line[points[[FindShortestTour[points][[-1]]]]]]`